# spring - unable to run spring boot app on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am following an [intro to rest apis with spring](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) but I cannot get it to run on a tomcat server (tried tomcat 7 and 9). In eclipse I do Run As -> Run Configurations -> Apache Tomcat which starts tomcat without errors but in the browser I get a 404 error (http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Susy)

[image: localhost:8080/greeting?name=Susy gives 404 error]

---

**EDIT**

<s>Trying to `mvn clean install` on the project and then `java -jar project.jar` gives</s>

```
Failed to load Main/Class manifest attribute from project.jar
```

**EDIT 2**

I exported the project to a runnable jar (and packaged the required libraries into the generated jar) but `java -jar project.jar` gives

```
java -jar restdemo.jar
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/Context
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
```

**EDIT 3**

I haven't deleted my m2 because I got a lot of stuff in there but I now create the spring start project through eclipse's spring tools. I added `Web` and `Actuator` as dependencies. When the project is created from `spring.io` I first notice that my company proxy blocks getting the spring parent pom:

```
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.9.RELEASE from/to <company>MavenRepository (http://maven-repository.<company>.net): 
Access denied to http://maven-repository.<company>.net/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.9.RELEASE.pom. 
Error code 403, URLBlocked and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

So I added to my pom

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

which removes the errors after maven update. But when I run the application as spring boot app I get this error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:383)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.spring.rest.demo.Restdemo2Application.main(Restdemo2Application.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

But the spring-core or spring-beans dependencies should all be imported via the parent right?

---

This is the implementation:

[image: spring boot app folder structure]

`App.class`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

`GreetingController.java`

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=true) String name) 
    {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

`Greeting.java`

```
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

In the [spring's deployment help](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications)
 it says

> When you run your application, Spring Boot will detect that you have a Spring MVC controller and start up an embedded Apache Tomcat 7 instance, by default

but when I run the app by project->run->java application I get

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at greeting.app.App.main(App.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

These are my tomcat settings

[image: tomcat settings in eclipse]

Comment: I am guessing one of your jars is corrupted. How did you create project.jar?

Comment: If you are using SpringBoot then you need to run it with embedded Tomcat server. Try running as Run -> Java Application, it will start the embedded tomcat and your code will be deployed in the tomcat. If its not working like this, then paste your pom.xml, may be some dependency is not correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

About the the last error you wrote, most likely one of your Maven jar file got corrupted as given by the message

```
invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

The simplest option is to delete your entire .m2 folder (where Maven stores its dependencies). Location of this repository (might be hidden)

- *nix/Mac ~/.m2
- Windows C:\Documents and Settings{your-username}.m2

To run a Spring Boot project you generally have two option
Use runnable jar with embedded Tomcat (or other servers), this is the preferred option. In this case after creating the jar, you can run it with

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

and it will run it as a server.
You can do this by setting packaging in your pom.xml to jar and add the spring-boot-maven-plugin to your plugins.
This is the preferred option.

Another option is to generate a .war file and deploy this to an application server.
In this case you set the packaging to war.

About this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
```

Seems like you did not correctly specify your project's dependencies. You should set `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent and add `spring-boot-starter` as a dependency.

I recommend to generate your project using https://start.spring.io/

You can set the packaging, add the `Web` starter and you will be good to go 
 to start implementing your logic. It will also add all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: @tenticon Yes, it should add these dependencies. I still think you have a corrupted dependency in your .m2, and it is not working because of that. When Maven encounters a 403 (sometimes) it writes jar with the HTML message. Please check whether the spring-boot-starter-web is valid (by actually opening it from .m2 folder as a zip).  If it is not valid delete it. Also check for empty jars in the .m2 folder. Run a Maven dependency tree, to check the dependencies (whether spring-beans and core is imported).